# rbp not allowed as SIB base?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, machine-code, addressing-mode

I'm quite new to x86-64 binary encoding. I'm trying to fix some old "assembler" code.

Anyways, I'm trying to do something like this (Intel syntax):

```
mov    [rbp+rcx], al
```

The assembler is currently generating this:

```
88 04 0D
```

but that doesn't seem to be a valid instruction. If I change out the base in the SIB-byte from `rbp` to some other register, it works fine. Another way to make it work is to add a one byte displacement of zero (`88 44 0D 00`). This seems to happen with other similar opcodes.

Why can't I use `rbp` there with `mod=00`?

Comment: Now I'm wondering which assembler you're using that it would generate the wrong instruction!

Comment: @AlexisWilke It's more of a joke than an assembler, but this thing: https://github.com/seattlerb/wilson I'm trying to adapt it for x86-64 and modern Ruby (for educational purposes!), and stumbled across this bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**See also https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#32.2F64-bit_addressing_2 or Intel's vol.2 manual for tables of encodings and footnotes for these special cases.**  This answer points out the special cases, and talks about why those design choices make some sense, i.e. what design problem they needed to solve.

---

The encoding that would mean `rbp` is an escape code for no base register (just a disp32 in SIB or RIP-relative rel32 in ModRM).  Most assemblers assemble `[rbp]` into `[rbp + disp8=0]`.

**Since you don't need it scaled, use `[rcx + rbp]` instead to avoid needing a disp8=0, because `rbp` *can* be an index.**

(SS and DS are always equivalent in long mode, so it doesn't matter that base=RBP implies SS while base=RCX implies using the DS segment.)

---

## x86 / x86-64 ModRM addressing mode encoding special cases

(from an answer I wrote on [Why are rbp and rsp called general purpose registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529449/why-are-rbp-and-rsp-called-general-purpose-registers/51347294#51347294)).  This question looks like the perfect place to copy or transplant this section.

**`rbp`/`r13` can't be a base register with no displacement**: that encoding instead means: (in ModRM) `rel32` (RIP-relative), or (in SIB) `disp32` with no base register.  (`r13` uses the same 3 bits in ModRM/SIB, so this choice simplifies decoding by not making the instruction-length decoder look at [the REX.B bit](https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#Encoding) to get the 4th base-register bit).  `[r13]` assembles to `[r13 + disp8=0]`.  `[r13+rdx]` assembles to `[rdx+r13]` (avoiding the problem by swapping base/index when that's an option).

**`rsp`/`r12` as a base register always needs a SIB byte**.  (The ModR/M encoding of base=RSP is escape code to signal a SIB byte, and again, more of the decoder would have to care about the REX prefix if `r12` was handled differently).

**`rsp` can't be an index register**.  This makes it possible to encode `[rsp]`, which is more useful than `[rsp + rsp]`.  (Intel could have designed the ModRM/SIB encodings for 32-bit addressing modes (new in 386) so SIB-with-no-index was only possible with base=ESP.  That would make `[eax + esp*4]` possible and only exclude `[esp + esp*1/2/4/8]`.  But that's not useful, so they simplified the hardware by making index=ESP the code for no index regardless of the base.  This allows two redundant ways to encode any base or base+disp addressing mode: with or without a SIB.)

**`r12` *can* be an index register**.  Unlike the other cases, this doesn't affect instruction-length decoding.  Also, it couldn't have been worked around with a longer encoding like the other cases can.  AMD  wanted AMD64's register set to be as orthogonal as possible, so it makes sense they'd spend a few extra transistors to check REX.X as part of the index / no-index decoding.  For example, `[rsp + r12*4]` requires index=r12, so having `r12` not fully generally purpose would make AMD64 a worse compiler target.

```
   0:   41 8b 03                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [r11]
   3:   41 8b 04 24             mov    eax,DWORD PTR [r12]      # needs a SIB like RSP
   7:   41 8b 45 00             mov    eax,DWORD PTR [r13+0x0]  # needs a disp8 like RBP
   b:   41 8b 06                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [r14]
   e:   41 8b 07                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [r15]
  11:   43 8b 04 e3             mov    eax,DWORD PTR [r11+r12*8] # *can* be an index
```

These all apply to 32-bit addressing modes as well; the encoding is identical except there's no EIP-relative encoding, just two redundant ways to encode disp32 with no base.

---

> This seems to happen with other similar opcodes.

ModRM encoding of r/m operands is always the same.  Some opcodes require a register operand, and some require memory, but the actual ModRM + optional SIB + optional displacement is fixed so the same hardware can decode it regardless of the instruction.

There are a few rare opcodes like `mov al/ax/eax/rax, [qword absolute_address]` that don't use ModRM encoding at all for their operands, but any that do use the same format.

Comment: Ah, could've looked at the tables here: https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#32.2F64-bit_addressing_2. Thank you.

Comment: @ollpu: yup, good link.  But you have to read it carefully to spot the patterns and the three special cases.  Updated this answer with a section I originally wrote for a different answer.