# x86 instruction "movb $5, var(,1)"

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I am reading a [tutorial](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs421/papers/x86-asm/asm.html) of x86 assembly on AT&T syntax, and I encountered this instructions

`movb $5, var(,1)` — store the value 5 into the byte at location var.

What does `(,1)` after `var` indicate? What is the general syntax for such suffix?

Comment: That's quite useless in this situation. Anyway, that's the at&t effective address syntax with some parts omitted. See the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMemory.html). At least GNU assembler v2.28 generates the same code for that as if you simply used `var`. Other versions might be forced to emit a SIB byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is unconventional style to say the least; I've never seen anyone write that before, for addressing a static label with no registers.**

---

It may be an attempt to indicate a SIB byte (with no base or index), instead of allowing the assembler to use a shorter encoding with just a ModRM byte.

(Yes, that's possible.  32-bit addressing modes have 2 redundant ways to encode `[disp32]` absolute addresses.  x86-64 redefines the shorter one as RIP-relative addressing.  See also [rbp not allowed as SIB base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522544/rbp-not-allowed-as-sib-base))

**But current GAS ignores it and encodes it the same as just `var`.**

**So maybe it's an attempt to remind you that this is a memory operand, like always using `[var]` in Intel-syntax instead of `mov var,  al`** (which is valid in MASM-style flavours of Intel syntax such as GNU `.intel_syntax`, but not NASM).

> What is the general syntax for such suffix?

Or maybe they're just doing it for consistency of always using the **`disp(basereg, idxreg, scale)`** syntax for memory operands, omitting unused parts.

---

Test source:

```
var:                  # this won't be in writeable memory, it will assemble but not run
movb  $5, var
movb  $5, var(,1)
movb  $5, (var)      # turns out this is valid, too!

#movb $5, var(%rip)  # RIP-relative is x86-64 only, but it's recommended when available.

# movb  $5, var()     # Error: junk `()' after expression
# movb  $5, (var,,1)  # also invalid
# movb  $5, (var,%ecx,1)       # also invalid.
# movb  $5, (var+%eax,%ecx,1)  # also invalid.
```

`as --version` prints `GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.31.1` on my system.

```
$ gcc -m32 -no-pie -nostdlib foo.s
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008049000
 # I just wanted a linked binary with real addresses filled in, not to run it.
 # entry = start of the .text section is fine.

$ objdump -drwC -Mintel a.out

08049000 <var>:
 8049000:       c6 05 00 90 04 08 05    mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x8049000,0x5
 8049007:       c6 05 00 90 04 08 05    mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x8049000,0x5
 804900e:       c6 05 00 90 04 08 05    mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x8049000,0x5
```

Clang 7.0's built-in assembler also accepts all 3 variants that GAS does, making an identical binary. (At least the `.text` section that I'm disassembling; probably some difference somewhere in another section.)

---

**So perhaps `cmp $1, (var)` is a good way to make memory operands explicit?**  But it's not great, because unlike Intel syntax, you can't just *add* registers to that, you'd have to move `var` outside the parens.