# How to copy a register and do `x*4 + constant` with the minimum number of instructions

Tags: assembly, x86, micro-optimization

I am new to x86 assembly. For example for the following instruction: multiply the contents of ESP by 4 and add 0x11233344, storing the result in EDI.

How do I represent this instruction in x86 assembly with minimum number of instructions?

```
push esp
mov edi, 4
mul edi
add edi, 0x11233344
```

Comment: Why are you doing `push esp`?  That modifies ESP and stores a copy of the old value to memory at `[esp]`, because ESP is the stack pointer..  Did you mean `mov eax, esp` to set up the implicit input operand for `mul`?  Are you sure sure you have a value in ESP where it makes sense to left-shift it and add a large constant?  Generally avoid using the stack pointer to hold temporary values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your asm doesn't make any sense (`push esp` copies to memory, not another register), and `mul edi` writes EDX:EAX not `edi`.  It does `EDX:EAX = EAX * src_operand`.  Read the manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MUL.html.  Or better, use `imul` instead unless you actually *need* the high-half output of the full 32x32 => 64-bit multiply.

Also, don't use the stack pointer register ESP to hold temporary values unless you know exactly what you're doing (e.g. you're in user-space, and you've made sure no signal handlers can asynchronously use the stack.)  stack-pointer * 4 + large-constant is *not* something that a normal program would ever do.

---

**Normally you could [do this in one LEA instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597055/using-lea-on-values-that-arent-addresses-pointers) but ESP is the only register that can't be an index in an x86 address mode.** See [rbp not allowed as SIB base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522544/rbp-not-allowed-as-sib-base)
 (The index is the part of an addressing mode that can have a 2-bit shift count applied, aka a scale factor).

I *think* our best bet is still just to copy ESP to EDI, then use LEA:

```
 mov  edi, esp
 lea  edi, [edi * 4 + 0x11223344]
```

Or you could copy-and-add with LEA, and *then* left shift, because the value we're adding has two zeros as its low bits (i.e. it's a multiple of 4).  So we can right shift it by 2 without losing any bits.

```
SHIFTED_ADD_CONSTANT equ 0x11223344 >> 2

  lea    edi, [esp + SHIFTED_ADD_CONSTANT]
  shl    edi, 2
```

The add before left-shifting will produce carry into the top 2 bits, but we're about to shift those bits out so it doesn't matter what's there.

This is also 2 uops, and *more* efficient on AMD Bulldozer-family CPUs  (no mov-elimination for GP-integer `mov`, and where a scaled index costs an extra cycle of latency for LEA).  Zen has mov-elimination but I think still the same LEA latencies so both versions are 2 cycle latency.  Even "complex" LEA has 2/clock throughput on Zen, or 4/clock for simple LEA (any ALU port).

But *less* efficient on Intel IvyBridge and later CPUs where the `mov` can run with zero latency (mov elimination), and the `[edi*4 + disp32]` addressing mode is still a fast 2-component LEA.  So on Intel CPUs with mov-elimination, the first version is 2 front-end uops, 1 unfused-domain uop for an execution unit, and only 1 cycle of latency.

Another 2-instruction option is to use a slower `imul` instead of a fast shift. (Addressing modes use a shift: even though it's written as `* 1 / 2 / 4 / 8`, it's encoded in a 2-bit shift-count field in machine code).

```
  imul  edi, esp, 4       ; this is dumb, don't use mul/imul for powers of 2.
  add   edi, 0x11223344
```

`imul` has 3 cycle latency on modern x86 CPUs which is pretty good, but is slower on old CPUs like Pentium 3.  Still not as good as 1 or 2-cycle latency for mov + LEA, and `imul` runs on fewer ports.

---

(Number of instructions is not usually the thing to optimize for; number of uops usually matters more, and latency / back-end throughput.  Also code-size in bytes of x86 machine code; different instructions are different lengths.)