# Can the LEA instruction mimic every MOV instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

Recently came across the [M/o/Vfuscator](https://github.com/xoreaxeaxeax/movfuscator)

> A complete single-instruction C compiler which compiles programs into
> "mov" instructions, and only "mov" instructions. Arithmetic,
> comparisons, jumps, function calls, and everything else a program
> needs are all performed through mov operations; there is no
> self-modifying code, no transport-triggered calculation, and no other
> form of non-mov cheating.

**Question**

I'm curious if every MOV instruction can be replaced with an equivalent LEA?

For example

```
 mov     rax, 10
 mov     rbx, rax
 ...
```

can be replaced with

```
 lea     rax, [10]
 lea     rbx, [rax]
 ...
```

**Update**

Oops, totally forgot that LEA cannot do a pointer dereference. For example

```
.data
     ten dq 10

.code

main proc

    mov     rax, offset ten
    mov     rbx, [rax]  ; <--- dereference, move 10 into rbx
     
    lea     rax, [ten]
                        ; <--- no dereference equivalent using lea
    ret
main endp

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have just written are identical, but `lea` is most often used to do some address calculations inside square braces `[]`, it can multiply 2 numbers add third number to those etc. in some places I've come across `lea` instruction doing just some math (and it is for that). when you have `struct` address for example and want to retrieve a member of it located, say `offset + 8` bytes away from offset you do `lea rax, [rbx+8]`, `rbx` being the address of struct. `mov` can be used to load addresses (just like `lea`), but values also. `mov rax, [rbx]` is equivalent to dereferencing a pointer pointed held in `rbx`. often times you'll see `mov rax, [rbx+8*4]` this is how you load the value of `int` array (assuming it takes 4 bytes to store ints on your system), equivalent in C would be `array[8]`. So to wrap up `lea` and `mov` could be used interchangeably when loading addresses in registers, but `lea` can't do pointer dereference, you need `mov` for that, or when storing values at memory addresses `lea` won't help, you need `mov` for those operations too. Note about doing math in square braces `[]` in `lea`, the thing is you have much more flexibility in terms of math with `lea`. Here is how to do math with `mov` when accessing memory to not break rules. [link](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html).

Answer (score 3):

No, LEA can't load or store from/to memory, unlike `mov eax, [rdi]` or `mov [rdi+rcx*8], rax`.
Movfuscator relies on using `mov` for table lookups to do logic, so this is a big problem. `lea` can only do addition (of registers and signed constants) and left-shift, so it's less powerful.  As well as not allowing access to anything but registers.

---

LEA can't mimic every immediate-source `mov`, since `mov r64, imm64` is the only x86-64 instruction that can use a 64-bit immediate (e.g. `mov rcx, 0xdeadbeefdeadbeef`).  `lea r64, [disp32]` can only use a sign-extended 32-bit absolute displacement.  (Conversely, RIP-relative LEA can do things MOV can't, being more efficient than `call $+5` / `pop rdi` / `add rdi, imm32`)

---

LEA can't read or write 8-bit registers, including inability to emulate `mov cl, ah` or similar.

LEA can copy register to register for 16, 32, and 64-bit registers, but less efficiently ([mov-elimination at register-rename time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all) is specific to `mov`).  Some instructions also need longer machine code, e.g. `lea eax, [rbp]` or `lea rax, [rsp]` take extra machine-code bytes because of addressing-mode special cases, while `mov eax, ebp` and `mov rax, rsp` are 2 and 3 bytes, respectively.  See *[rbp not allowed as SIB base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522544/rbp-not-allowed-as-sib-base)*.  This also affects `[r12]` and `[r13]`, which use the same ModRM values but distinguished by a bit in REX.

```
  401000:       8d 03                   lea    eax,[rbx]       # normal length, no REX
  401002:       89 d8                   mov    eax,ebx         # equivalent MOV
  401004:       41 8d 03                lea    eax,[r11]       # normal length, with a REX
  401007:       44 89 d8                mov    eax,r11d

  40100a:       8d 04 24                lea    eax,[rsp]    # [rsp] can only be encoded with a SIB byte
  40100d:       89 e0                   mov    eax,esp      # but mov reg,reg uses register-direct
  40100f:       41 8d 04 24             lea    eax,[r12]
  401013:       44 89 e0                mov    eax,r12d

  401016:       8d 45 00                lea    eax,[rbp+0x0]  # [rbp] can only be encoded with disp8=0 (or disp32 but that's longer)
  401019:       89 e8                   mov    eax,ebp
  40101b:       41 8d 45 00             lea    eax,[r13+0x0]
  40101f:       44 89 e8                mov    eax,r13d

  401022:       88 e1                   mov    cl,ah    # LEA can't do this at all.
```

---

Of course, the reason you'd use LEA is to do math in the addressing mode, not copy a register or set it to an immediate constant.  e.g. to copy-and-increment like `mov` + `add`, and/or shift-and-add registers.
*[Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597055/using-lea-on-values-that-arent-addresses-pointers)*

Comment: Is it a typo for `add` ? " e.g. to copy-and-increment like `mov` + `and`, ..."